# Не переписывает переменную при условии

Tags: python-3.x

Почему при флаге True не переписывает переменную list_num2?

```
def func(*num,flag):
    list_num1 = []
    list_num2 = []
    if flag == False:
        for number in num:
            if number % 2 == 0:
                list_num1.append(number)
    return list_num1
    if flag == True:
        for number in num:
            if number % 2 != 0:
                list_num2.append(number)
    return list_num2
print(func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, flag=True))
```

Comment: потому что вы сразу выходите из функции

Comment: Спасибо! Sergey Gornostaev донес до моего мозга что означает return. Это я просто не взял во внимание в своем коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `return` заканчивает выполнение функции. До `if flag == True` выполнение просто не доходит.

Comment: Спасибо, хотя это такая простая вещь но я ее упустил из своего понимания.